# Stored energy (and others) of RC circuit

Tags: dc, circuit-analysis

In a circuit shown below me and a friend of mine discussed how we could calculate this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjZ4Yn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

He simplified the circuit by stating the resistors and capacitors are in parallel, and hence it can be simplified to a capacitor of 17 farad and a resistor of 142k ohm.  So energy stored would be: \$ \tfrac{1}{2} CV^2 = 0.5 \cdot 17 \cdot 36= 306 J\$
I thought this was wrong, and one could simplify the circuit to 3 "parallel" rc-circuits, each consisting of a 47k ohm resistor, 50 F capacitor and a 6/3 = 2 V dc supply. So total energy that could be stored is:
\$3\cdot\tfrac{1}{2}CV^2 = 1.5 \cdot 50 \cdot 4 = 300 J\$

What is the correct approach, or should a complete different method be taken?

Comment: What circuit? Add a schematic...

Comment: @MattYoung oops, multi-tabbing stackexchange and forgot it >< (though is it worth a negative vote?)

Comment: "0.5 * 17 * 36" can't possibly equal 306 J. Multiplying any number of dimensionless quantities can't ever result in a value of Joules.  -1 for blatant sloppiness with units.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Do you really wish for a "war" on use of units during a calculation? I've always learned to leave those out -and always use the standard SI unites- so that the magnitude and size of the units can be seen easily and there's no difficulty with "m" vs "M" etc.

Comment: @Paul23 Yes. Olin is the minister for war and proper-units [tm]. I'd agree that if you give the formula first using relevant symbols, and follow it with a numeric equivalent then it is (usually) clear and adequate - BUT, as that is what I often do I'd have to , wouldn't I ? :-). BUT there IS great difficulty with swapping m and M as they are both formally defined symbols and differ in magnitude by a factor of 10^9 (as I know you know). m/F conflation will not usually cause errors but does bend the path of smooth thinking and should be avoided where possible (ie almost always.)

Comment: Both approaches are equally valid. Not rounding to the extent that it causes you confusion is almost always a good idea. Considering 3 x 50 uF at 2V each is probably closer to basic principles as you don't need to make the otherwise underived "3 capacitors in series" assumption

Comment: @paul23: There is no war. Using incorrect units is wrong, and has no place in engineering. Sometimes it is sloppiness, sometimes it is due to a true misconception, but in either case lead to ambiguity and misintepretation by others. In your case, you stated a dimensionless value was equal to a value in Joules. That's just plain wrong. Even worse is that you spent the effort arguing about it instead of fixing it. As for the rounding, I never said anything against that. Rounding to 17 F in your case is perfectly appropriate, the only error was not recognizing the two answers were the same.

Comment: @OlinLathrop "Using incorrect units is wrong, and has no place in engineering." I did not use incorrect units did I? I just didn't include the dimensions as they can be deduced from the context and on top of that - the values are not important. Have you ever heard of "quick guesses" and not caring about values but about methods?

Comment: @paul: Yes you did use units incorrectly. That's the point. Once again, "0.5 * 17 * 36" is dimensionless, yet you equated that to a value in units of Joules. That is using units incorrectly, and quite blatantly so. And no, saying the units can be decuded from context is not good enough when you're writing equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than arguing about combining resistors and capacitors in parallel and series, recall that, in steady state, the *current through a capacitor is zero*.  Thus, assuming steady state, *replace the capacitors with open circuits*.

Then, *by inspection*, there is 2V across each resistor (if the resistor values were different, one would used voltage division to determine the voltage across each).

Thus, each capacitor has 2V across.  Since the three capacitor values are identical, the stored energy is simply:

$$W = 3 \cdot \dfrac{1}{2}50F\cdot(2V)^2 = 300J$$

If the capacitor values were different, the calculation would be:

$$W = \dfrac{(2V)^2}{2}(C_1 + C_2 + C_3) $$

If the resistor values were different too, the calculation would be:

$$W = \dfrac{(6V)^2}{2(R_1 + R_2 + R_3)^2}(R_1^2C_1 + R_2^2C_2 + R_3^2C_3) $$

Answer (score 1):

You have a rounding error in the first calculation - the three 50 F capacitors in series will be 16.666666666666... F, not 17.  Using that value, I get the same answer both ways.